# Not able to display data with AngularJS in Chrome App

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

Hi I'm building a chrome app which saves and retrieves data from the server. I do not have any issue while saving data to DB. But console.log shows undefined when I'm trying to retrieve. The web app does not have this issue.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="FrmController">
    <h4>Total Tasks: {{tasks.length}}</h4>
    <br/>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in tasks">
        <!--<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" ng-click="goCats = !goCats" ng-model="todo.done" value="{{todo.task_name}}">-->
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" ng-model="todo.done" value="{{todo.task_name}}">
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}"> {{todo.task_name}}</span> 
        <span class="test">
        <a id="done-modal-button-{{todo.done}}" ng-click='onCompleteTask(todo)' ng-model="todo.done" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-show="todo.done">Done</a> 
        <!--<a ng-click='editTask(todo)' editable-text="{{todo.task_name}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Edit</a>-->
        <a id="delete-modal-button" ng-click='taskDelete(todo)' class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-show="todo.done">Delete</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function FrmController($scope, $http) { 
 var page = "http://localhost:8080/fetch_task.php";
$http.get(page).success(function(response) {$scope.tasks = response;});
console.log($scope.tasks);
}
```

Console.log shows undefined. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

This function call is asynchronous. What this means is:

```
function FrmController($scope, $http) { 
  var page = "http://localhost:8080/fetch_task.php"; // 1st to be executed
  $http.get(page).success( // 2nd to be executed, but it only initiates the request
    function(response) { // will be executed later, only when the response is ready
      $scope.tasks = response;
    }
  );
  console.log($scope.tasks); // 3rd to be executed - not assigned yet
}
```

[This article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) gives a good overview of how this works, using the promise mechanism. One executes a function that will yield results later, and indicates what to do with results - but it will not be done immediately.

For instance, if you wrote

```
function FrmController($scope, $http) { 
  var page = "http://localhost:8080/fetch_task.php";
  $http.get(page).success(
    function(response) {
      $scope.tasks = response;
      console.log($scope.tasks);
    }
  );
}
```

it would work.

Comment: Then maybe success callback is not called? Add an error callback and see if there's any errors.